# differences in .zip format created with winrar and with 7-zip

Tags: zip, 7zip, difference, winrar, archiving

all.

I'm using a 3rd party lib to archive/decompress some files.
Input/output format is .zip.

But I've discovered that the lib could read well archives created with WinRAR, but cannot read archives created with 7-zip.

Could anyone tell me what the problem is and how it could be fixed.

hex view of starting of archive, created with winRar:

> 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 EC 88 25 45 6e 1a ....

hex view of starting of archive, created with 7-zip:

> 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 ED 88 25 45 6e 1a ....

the difference is in byte `EC` and `ED`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

7-Zip archives can be created using several different [compression formats](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) which are not compatible with standard ZIP compression/decompression libraries based for example on [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org) source code.

Applications like WinRAR and Total Commander supporting creation/extraction of ZIP files natively use therefore additionally a DLL for extracting files from non standard 7-Zip archives.

See question **Can I use the EXE or DLL files from 7-Zip in a Commercial Application?** on [FAQ](http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html) page of 7-Zip.

Answer (score 2):

This is the header structure of a ZIP file:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             BYTE                                    |
|0x0 0x1 0x2 0x3|0x4 0x5|0x6 0x7| 0x8   0x9 |0xA  0xB|0xC  0xD|       |
+---------------+-------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+
|  signature    |version| flags |compression|mod time|mod date| CRC32 |
+---------------+-------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-------+
| 50  4B  03  04| 14  00| 00  00|  08    00 |EC/ED 88| 25   45|       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- **signature** is always 0x50 0x4B 0x03 0x04 (as in your case). 0x50 = 'P', 0x4B = 'K' ([Phillip Katz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Katz))
- **version** needed to extract (0x14 0x00 = 20 -> ZIP 2.0)
- general purpose bit **flags** (no flags, your file is not crypted / default language encoding)
- **compression method** is deflate (08)

So the only things that change is the modification time (just some minutes).

Even the first two bytes of the CRC32 are the same. If *the only difference* is the `EC` / `ED` value, the problem shouldn't be the archive content.

Further references: https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html